# How can i find the list of nodes in a redis cluster?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I have created a redis cluster client as follows:

```
// create uri
RedisURI redisURI = RedisClusterURIUtil.toRedisURI(URI.create("redis://localhost:6379"));

RedisClusterClient redisClusterClient = RedisClusterClient.create(redisURI);

StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, String> connection = redisClusterClient.connect();
```

Now as the connection will discover all the nodes in the redis cluster ...

How can i find list of all nodes that my cluster client has discovered ? Is there any method that is available

Answer (score 0):

Use `connection.getPartitions().getPartitions()` to get `List` of `RedisClusterNode` or `connection.getPartitions().iterator()` to iterate them.